# Diseño moderno en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo en mente realizar un proyecto de escritorio en visual studio y me gustaría que no quedase la típica apariencia simple de Windows forms. Había pensado intentar hacerlo en WPF, ¿Se pueden conseguir cosas modernas con la instalación básica de visual studio o por el contrario me recomendáis instalar alguna extensión-pluggin de algún tercero? He oído algo de Silverlight pero no sé si será conveniente...

Comment: WPF permite una apariencia bastante bonita visualmente, y en el caso que quieras algo más complejo y concreto puedes usar Blend, se instala al instalar Visual Studio.

Comment: Si quieres hacer algo moderno te tocara hacer tus propios form, con esto me refiero quitar los botones de cerrar, minimizar, maximizar y te tocara dibujarlos y programarlos por tu propia cuenta, llevando mas tiempo el desarrollo. Yo digo que no reinventes la rueda.